# Failed when running flutter project on Android Emulator ... I need some help to fix this please

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, keystore, keytool

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            474.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I don't know what should I do for this ...
I tried many ways but doesn't work with me until now ...
I hope I find the solution ...

Comment: refer to this and see what went wrong your your creating and referencing of you app's Keystore, https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore

Answer (score 0):

I think this [question already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233117/execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesigningrelease-flutter-error), your key.properties file is probably the issue.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: java.io.IOException: 
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolExcepti
on: Failed to create keystore.
```

According to this gradle has failed to create the keystore file.this is probably due to your keystore.properties file missing. Have you signed your app?  If not u can follow this guide [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android).